# Create a url shortcut for a ajax search field 3

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a shortcut to a page with a search value included. For example in this page :

https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/tables/data.html

There is a search field in the middle of the screen which is live (ajax) and when you type
1.8 it limits results to 8.
Can i create a url to show directly this "filtered data page " ?
something like this ->

[https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/tables/data.html?Search="1.8"](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/tables/data.html?Search=%221.8%22)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to pass a parameter to the search field and the search field functionality is done with javascript. In this case, you can pass a parameter like in your example, but then it will have to be in the code of the search functionality that your read the parameter and act accordingly, for example by reading `window.location.search` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search